# Android - issue writing files to card on a Nexus 7

Tags: android

I'm having a bit of trouble running my application on a Nexus 7 and wonder if it's some sort of quirk with this device that can be worked around, as it works fine on a HTC Wildfire S.

I'm trying to write a midi file to the SD card, and then call that same midi file into the android MediaPlayer.  The problem is, the file is only written after I close the application, which is no good for my purposes.

On the Wildfire, it writes the file in real-time, and then calls it into the media player straight away with no issue.

Here's the code

```
try{
         mf.writeToFile ("/mnt/sdcard/temp.mid");

         }
         catch (IOException e){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }





    String PATH_TO_FILE = "/mnt/sdcard/temp.mid";    
    mediaPlayer = new  MediaPlayer();

    try {
   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
   mediaPlayer.prepare();
```

Answer (score 1):

do not hard code the path.

Instead try this,

```
 String PATH_TO_FILE =   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"temp.mid";
```

the same way for writetoFile() also.